# React How to return div and variable value for another component

Tags: reactjs

How to return my div and my variable view to another component? I can't do 2 returns?

```
class Toolbar extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
          view:''
        }
      }
  
      render(){
        return(
          <div className="button-toolbar">
            <button className="button" onClick={() => this.setState({view: 1})}>1</button>
            <button className="button" onClick={() => this.setState({view: 2})}>2</button>
            <button className="button" onClick={() => this.setState({view: 3})}>3</button>
            <button className="button">Wallet</button>          
          </div>
        )
         
        return {this.state.view}
```

I want to return the value of my button to send it into another component

App.js :

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Toolbar></Toolbar>
        <View view=/*Return toolbar value*/></View>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to accomplish. What is the end result you're going for?

Comment: @Nick I want to return the result from my button (1 2 or 3)

Comment: Do you want the buttons to still show when you do?

Comment: I just edited my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the `this.state.view` to show alongside the buttons, you can simply include it in the same `render` return:

```
class Toolbar extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
          view:''
        }
      }
  
      render(){
        return(
          <div className="button-toolbar">
            <button className="button" onClick={() => this.setState({view: 1})}>1</button>
            <button className="button" onClick={() => this.setState({view: 2})}>2</button>
            <button className="button" onClick={() => this.setState({view: 3})}>3</button>
            <button className="button">Wallet</button>
            {this.state.view}       
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

If you want to *not* show the buttons once the `view` value is set, you can just return early if a condition is met.

```
class Toolbar extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
          view:''
        }
      }
  
      render(){
        if (this.state.view) {
          return this.state.view;
        }

        return (
          <div className="button-toolbar">
            <button className="button" onClick={() => this.setState({view: 1})}>1</button>
            <button className="button" onClick={() => this.setState({view: 2})}>2</button>
            <button className="button" onClick={() => this.setState({view: 3})}>3</button>
            <button className="button">Wallet</button>  
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

### Edit: Sharing state between components

If you need to share this state between a sibling component, you should generally raise the state up to the nearest common parent. In this case, that's `App.js`. It might look like this:

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = { view: "" };
    this.setView = this.setView.bind(this);
  }

  setView(view) {
    this.setState({ view });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Toolbar setView={this.setView}></Toolbar>
        <View view={view}></View>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And then your `Toolbar` component wouldn't need state anymore, but would use `this.props.setView` to set the view on the parent component.

**Toolbar.js**

```
class Toolbar extends Component {
      render(){
        return(
          <div className="button-toolbar">
            <button className="button" onClick={() => this.props.setView(1)}>1</button>
            <button className="button" onClick={() => this.props.setView(2)}>2</button>
            <button className="button" onClick={() => this.props.setView(3)}>3</button>
            <button className="button">Wallet</button>          
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: ok Thank you ! How can I get the return value to my other component ?

Comment: This will generally require you to lift state up to the closest common component. For example, since `Toolbar` and `View` both need the stateful value, you'll want to maintain state at the `App.js` level. You can then pass the state (and state-setters) down to each component.

Comment: @cryptomania14 see my updated answer about lifting state up to `App.js`. I hope this makes sense, let me know if it doesn't!